# Get h3 element of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<a class="prev" onClick="load('prev')">
  <span class="icon-wrap"></span>
  <h3><strong>Alexis</strong> Tsipras</h3>
</a>
```

I want to modify the text of `h3`. How I can do that?

---

One of the many things I tried:

```
$(".prev + span + h3").text();
```

but it returned an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `span` is not siblings of `.prev`(it is children of `.prev`).

Change
 `$(".prev + span + h3").text();`  to `$(".prev span + h3").text();`

Comment: Thank you, I understand the concept. Now I have to understand why I got downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".prev h3").html("<p>Hello World</p>"); // To set HTML Content

$(".prev h3").text("Hello World"); // To set Plain Text
```

You need to use the correct `CSS Selector`, `div + p` Selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements

```
$(".prev h3").text(); // Will fetch the text
```

Comment: What's the difference between `.prev h3` and `.prev + h3`?

Comment: Hmm, so `.prev h3` and `.prev + h3` will have the same result in that particular example?

Comment: OK thanks @A.Wolff. I got it. Now I have to understand why I was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one `h3` element on your page you can simply target that one:

```
 $('h3').text();
```

If you have more than one you indeed need to use context. You can do this:

```
<a class="prev">
  <span class="icon-wrap"></span>
  <h3><strong>Alexis</strong> Tsipras</h3>
</a>


$('.prev').click(function() {
  $(this).find('h3').text('hello');
});
```

Comment: Bravo for showing two approaches, that I understood nicely. Now I have to see why I got downvoted.